# Inline if statement that Intellij understands

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, twirl

I'm trying to create some sort of `class="active"` functionality using Twirl and Play 2.3 but I can't find a solution that works, is short and doesn't throw my Intellij syntax all over the place.

This is what I currently have:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li @(if (request.uri == "/") Html("""class="active""""))><a href="@routes.Application.home()">Home</a></li>
    <li @(if (request.uri == "/about") Html("""class="active""""))><a href="@routes.Application.about()">About</a></li>
    <li @(if (request.uri == "/features") Html("""class="active""""))><a href="@routes.Application.features()">Features</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is what Intellij thinks of it:
[image: Screenshot of Intellij]

Comment: Does this compile, but IntelliJ doesn't like it?  What version of IntelliJ are you running?  I think Play support is only available in Ultimate.

Comment: Intellij is a mess with twirl and play templates, it compiles but the ide will highlight the code as erroneous, personally when writing templates I simply compile form sbt, IDEA can't be trusted on this.

Comment: @BenReich I'm running the latest snapshot I believe with the Play plugin etc. I find that when I right click and select "Run Play App" it skips the complete syntax error check. And if I really made a mistake Play will tell me in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, IntelliJ sometimes is confused with view's syntax, anyway you can create i.e. custom util for adding (or not) the active class (Java sample)

```
package utils;

import play.api.templates.Html;
import play.mvc.Http;

public class AttrHelpers {
    public static Html setActiveClass(String requiredPath, Http.Request request) {
        return (requiredPath.equals(request.uri())) ? Html.apply("class=\"active\"") : null;
    }
}
```

So then you can use it in your views like:

```
<li @utils.AttrHelpers.setActiveClass("/about", request) >
    <a href="@routes.Application.about()">About</a>
</li>

<li @utils.AttrHelpers.setActiveClass("/features", request) >
    <a href="@routes.Application.features()">Features</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Simple and effective solution, thanks! Intellij likes it too from the looks of it :)

Comment: Just tip: the same way you can create i.e. helper for building whole `li` tag with link inside

Comment: I already tought of that haha ;) awesome you brought it up too